# Express Passport Google Strategy - using res.redirect

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, google-oauth

I have an express app which manages authentication via Passport with support for both local and Google strategies.

At the moment I support account creation via Google auth but actually a user's Google account doesn't contain all the info that my application requires. Because of this I would like to redirect uses who don't have a local account to my own account creation and only support account linking (i.e. their local account can be linked to Google account for authorization).

The problem is that I would normally do this via `res.redirect` but `res` is not available in the Google Strategy - what is the best way to handle this?

In 'index.js' where I define my routes I define `const passportGoogle = require('../handlers/google');` which has the details of my Google Strategy.

Further down in `index.js` I have my `authenticate` and `authorise` routes:

```
/* GOOGLE ROUTES FOR AUTHENTICATION*/

router.get('/google',
    passportGoogle.authenticate('google', 
    { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

router.get('/google/callback', 
    passportGoogle.authenticate('google', 
    {
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: 'Failed Login!',
        successRedirect: '/account',
        successFlash: 'You are logged in!'

    }
));

/* GOOGLE ROUTES FOR AUTHORISATION - IE A USER IS ALREADY LOGGED IN AND WANTS TO CONNECT THEIR GOOGLE ACCOUNT*/

// send to google to do the authentication
router.get('/connect/google', 
    passportGoogle.authorize('google', 
    { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }
));

// the callback after google has authorized the user
router.get('/connect/google/callback',
    passportGoogle.authorize('google', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/'
    })
);
```

As above my Google strategy is defined in `google.js`:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var User = require('../models/User');
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENTID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENTSECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:7777/google/callback",
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  // google will send back the token and profile
function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous
    process.nextTick(function() {

        // check if the user is already logged in
        if (!req.user) {
            // find the user in the database based on their facebook id
            User.findOne({ 'google.id': profile.id }, function(err, user) {

                // if there is an error, stop everything and return that
                // ie an error connecting to the database
                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                // if the user is found, then log them in
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
                } else { <--here is where I want to redirect
                    //currently I create a new user but i really want to redirect them to create a local account
                    // if there is no user found with that google id, create them
                    var newUser            = new User();

                    // set all of the facebook information in our user model
                    newUser.google.id = profile.id;
                    newUser.google.token = token;
                    newUser.name = profile.displayName;
                    newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;

                    // save our user to the database
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;

                        // if successful, return the new user
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }

            });

        } else {
            const user = User.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: req.user._id },
                { $set: {"user.google.id":profile.id, 
                        "user.google.token":accessToken, 
                        "user.google.name":profile.displayName, 
                        "user.google.email":profile.emails[0].value
                    }
                },   
                { new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query' }
            )
            .exec();
            return done(null, user);
            req.flash('success', 'Google details have been added to your account'); 
            res.redirect(`back`); 
        }
    });
}));

module.exports = passport;
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: "I would normally do this via res.redirect but res is not available in the Google Strategy." But you can access it after the `passport.authenticate` middleware:

    router.get('/google/callback', 
        passportGoogle.authenticate('google'),
        (req, res) => {
            if req.isAuthenticated() {
            //do what you want with the res here
            }
        }
));

Comment: thanks @AndyTaton so should I be moving some of the logic in google.js into the route definition in index.js?

Comment: That's what I would recommend. Your route definition is already doing res.redirect in abbreviated form with {successRedirect: ...}; I'm proposing you expand that by getting rid of failureRedirect/successRedirect, and instead adding more detailed code to a middleware that comes after passport.authenticate. Good luck!